# ViewTreeObserver does not call onScrollChanged after adding OnScrollChangedListener

Tags: android, scroll, android-view

I have a layout with a webview and a button. The button is visible but becomes visible once the webview is scrolled. I'm using ViewTreeObserver, but for some reason, onScrollChanged is not called. Am I misunderstanding how onScrollChanged is called?

```
this.licenseAgreementView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.licenseAgreementView);
ViewTreeObserver observer = this.licenseAgreementView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
    public void onScrollChanged() {
    makeButtonVisible();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear from the code if the `LicenseAgreementView` is the `WebView` or the containing layout.  If the latter, try fetching the WebView and adding the observer to that.

Comment: LicenseAgreementView is a WebView

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had to attach a GlobalLayoutListener to my scrollView and then on LayoutChanged I had to add the scrollListener.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewTreeObserver observer = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
            observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    //Your code here
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Wow, this code works even for a ScrollView inside another ScrollView!

Comment: Works for me.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
    final View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    final ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener onScrollChangedListener =
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {

            //your code here -->
            makeButtonVisible();

        }

    };


    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            ViewTreeObserver observer = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
            observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener);
            return false;

        }

    });
```

Try this, works for my.